# Unable to write cache file

Tags: php, symfony, ssh, installation, acl

I have a problem on a project that i took back.
There is a problem with the right ( i think ) for `www-data`; I'm on a sf 2.0 project and the error comes too on other (working and in production ) website..

So i followed the official symfony docs: 
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/installation.html

The three solutions have been tried with success, the setfacl are working, but there is still the error when i'm trying to clear the cache.

The project is working, and there is no problem with it on the server.

Even the `umask(0000)` still does nothing !

I really don't know where and what to find..
Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here is the solution:

I don't understand the -3 but ok.
As i said, i search for the solution, and follow the documentation here:
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/installation.html

`www-data` had the rights but i still getting the error.

I deployed the project again and i did `php app/check.php`

Then i got this error:

```
[[ ERROR ]] Checking that the "date.timezone" setting is set: FAILED
        *** Set the "date.timezone" setting in php.ini (like Europe/Paris) ***
```

Then

```
sudo mv /etc/php5/cli/php.ini /etc/php5/cli/php.ini.bak
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

Then i gave a value to `date.timezone` and all worked fine with a new `php app/check.php`

Problem solved !

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the Apache user in your system is called `www-data`. If it has any other name like `www` or `apache`, change permissions with `setfacl` or `chmod +a` accordingly.

Also, delete `app/cache` and `app/logs` folders content manually with the following command:

```
rm -rf app/cache/* app/logs/*
```

Comment: No, the name is really www-data.. and i already tried to delete manualy.. thanks